# Segment-Cylinder intersection

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

What is the complete code (C#, pseudo, does not matter) for calculating the resulting segment (or its absence) for the intersection of asegment and a cylinder?

The segment is defined by `Vector3`(x,y,z) as **Start** and`Vector3`(x,y,z) as **End**.

The cylinder is defined by the same parameters plus a value for **Radius**.

Comment: You may find what you're looking for with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078401/trying-to-optimize-line-vs-cylinder-intersection) from SO. The last answer seems to fit your request, remember to up-vote that if it helped you.

Comment: You don't tell us what you've tried and what the specific problem is.

Comment: Hm, it's generally a bad practice to _ask_ for code. Pseudocode is fine, because it's just that vague as not to be copy-pasted somewhere. By pseudocode I understand any human readable crap though. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Mathematical explanation with readable symbols and LaTeX format](http://mathbin.net/92265)** - great for 1st or 2nd year undergrad students or skilled high-school people.

Well, if you need to understand the maths behind it rather than copy-pasting some code that might not be the good one (it's not clear whether it will work or not judging from the SO code). 
Here are the steps:

- It's easier to find the intersection points if the cylinder is aligned with the Z axis of your Oxyz frame.

Let *v = normalize(Cylinder.End - Cylinder.Start)*

Compute *w = cross(v, vec3(0,0,1))*. If *w*'s not the null vector, you have to perform a *T* transform for both Cylinder and Segment to align the scene with the oZ axis:

*T = Rotation(w, arccos(dot(v,z)) ) x Translation( - Cylinder.Start)*
Use this transform to find the coordinates of the transformed Cylinder and Segment: *Cylinder2 = T x Cylinder1*, *Segment2 = T x Segment1*. For simplicity, I'll call the results Cylinder and Segment.

- Since the Cylinder is aligned with the Z axis, the equation of a point that lies on its surface is *x^2 + y^2 = r^2*, there's no constraint on the *z* component.

Let the equation of your segment be *(x0 + t(x1-x0), y0 + t(y1-y0), z0 + t(z1-z0))* where  *Segment.Start(x0,y0,z0)* and *Segment.End(x1,y1,z1)*. For simplicity, let's forget about *v, w* and all those letters that were used until now and call *x1-x0 = u, y1-y0 = v, z1-z0 = w*.

That means that a POINT on the segment is written as *vec3(x0+tu, y0+tv, z0+tw)*, where *t* should be in the [0,1] interval! Remember the condition for a POINT to also lie ON the SURFACE of the Cylinder? Now we get:

-- *(x0+tu)^2 + (y0 + tv)^2 = r^2*
which is equivalent to

-- *(u^2 + v^2)t^2 + 2(u x0 + v y0)t + x0^2 + y0^2 - r^2 = 0.*

Let *A = (u^2 +v^2), B= 2(u x0 + v y0)t, C= x0^2 + y0^2 -r^2*. You end up with a quadratic equation. *Delta = B^2 - 4AC*.

- Discussion:

If *Delta <0* you have no intersection.

If *Delta = 0*, the segment is tangent to the cylinder.

If *Delta > 0*, you solving for *t* gives you *t1* and *t2*.

Plug *t1* and *t2* in the POINT ON SEGMENT equation and get your P1 and P2 points that are CANDIDATES.

Remember, *t1* and *t2* must be between [0 and 1] in order for P1 and P2 to be points on your segment. If one of them is outside [0,1], it means your segment has an endpoint inside the cylinder. If both *t1,t2* are outside [0,1], the supporting LINE of the segment intersects the cylinder, but not your segment.

One last checkup, P1.z and P2.z should be between 0 and Cylinder.End.Z, because you work with *finite* cylinders.

Wrap-up: you have to plug in your *t1*, *t2* values in the INITIAL SEGMENT equation to recover the intersection points. That's it, I don't have the time to sum it up in a C# snippet, but I hope you understand what to do.